# Trying to see content of map

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dictionary

Hi I'm trying to see the content of a map with the following code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/demos", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")
    public @ResponseBody String getPartnerIdClusters(Model model) {
            Map<Integer, List<Cluster>> partnerIdClusterMap = partnerService.getPartnerIdClusterMap(true, true);

            return "partnerIdClusterMap: " + partnerIdClusterMap;
    }
```

Which gave me the following output in the browser:

```
partnerIdClusterMap: {2=nl.irp.globetrotting.model.Cluster@7499394a}
```

After that I had tried this code:

```
    String line = "test: /n";
    for (Object entry : partnerIdClusterMap.values().toArray()) {
             line += entry;
             line += "/n";
    }
    return "partnerIdClusterMap " + line;
```

But that didn't work either because it has given me the following output:

```
partnerIdClusterMap test: /nnl.irp.globetrotting.model.Cluster@63769066/n
```

I already know that it is the `Cluster` with  id 3. Here is a screenshot of it:
link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x97dt.png

Here is how the `getPartnerIdClusterMap()` method looks like (in case you want to know):

```
@Override
    public Map<Integer, List<Cluster>> getPartnerIdClusterMap(boolean minorOnly, boolean foreignCountriesOnly) {
        BooleanBuilder predicate = new BooleanBuilder();
        if (minorOnly) {
            predicate.and(qCluster.type.eq(ClusterType.MINOR));
        }
        if (foreignCountriesOnly) {
            predicate.and(qPartner.country.code2.ne("nl"));
        }

        return from(qCluster)
                .innerJoin(qCluster.partner, qPartner)
                .where(predicate)
                .where(qPartner.country.code2.ne("nl"))
                .map(qPartner.id, GroupBy.list(qCluster));

    }
```

**This is what I gladly want to know:**

So I gladly want to see the `Cluster`with all the values from the row.

Comment: you can override the method toString(Object o) at your Cluster class.
If you are using an API, you will need Cast the entry and use all access method or variable from Cluster Object and create the String to show all information you'll need.

Comment: Better yet, you could return `partnerIdClusterMap` directly (adjusting `getPartnerIdClusters`'s signature) to serialize the map into JSON "for free".

Comment: @kryger Ah I did return partnerIdClusterMap,   but could you maybe show me how to adjust it or give me a example, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring MVC should be able to convert maps to JSON, with the help of a message converter. Using Spring Boot, just returning maps works for me - a *MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter* is automatically configured. As I recall, before using Spring Boot, I just had to configure an *ObjectMapper*, and then returning the map was working. So, in summary, I think that

1. Using Spring Boot, returning a map should work.
2. If not using Spring Boot, an *ObjectMapper* (and maybe also a *MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter*) might be needed to be configured.
3. If the returned map holds things that the *ObjectMapper* can't convert by default, it might need you to supply some converting customization. Help material on *Jackson (now called fasterxml) ObjectMapper* will have more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
partnerIdClusterMap: {2=nl.irp.globetrotting.model.Cluster@7499394a}
```

Basically you are printing the values that you specified. In this case you are printing the integer and then the list object populated with Cluster Objects. 
Consider to iterate partnerIdClusterMap in your weblogic and extract the values with the methods provided by it or override the toString method of the object to get a full line with details.